How to Model a Solar Water Preheating System?
I would like to model a solar water preheating system in terms of a control system. Here is a diagram of what I am thinking about.

The cycle begins at the water tank with a thermostat set at a reference voltage r(t). The tank has a temperature sensor h(t) with a restriction R. Water is circulated by a pump at a presumably constant mass flow rate and flows through the heat exchanger. I am also assuming the volume of water in the tank is constant so the mass at any one time is constant.
In my transfer function block diagram, would I need to model both mechanical and thermodynamic elements in the same model or am I only concerned with the pump and sensor and some type of controller as shown below? A is the linearized comparator gain.

If I do have to include both types of elements, thermodynamic as well as mechanical, how do I go from mass flow rate to heat? I am assuming the mass flow rate would be the output of the pump with the input being the voltage to control it.
I am referring to the tank and the heat exchanger as the thermodynamic elements. Since no state variables change in my tank, would that just make that block a constant? If so any idea how I would calculate it?

Put a solar loop in the tank, that way antifreeze can be used in the collector to avoid freezing. There are many sources that are relevant one is Solar Thermal Engineering by Duffie & Beckman.

Why is the flow rate constant? if you control the system based on solar energy input, then the flow rate needs to vary, like when a cloud goes over...

I was thinking that the flow rate would be constant and when the water got up the temperature in tank. The flow would stop.
